# Jconsole unable to connect to local process

Tags: visualvm, jconsole

Jconsole is unable to connect to a local process. I tried the same in VisualVM and I am getting the following message:
 'Data not available because JMX connection to the JMX agent could not be established.'

Yesterday, Jconsole didn't connected initially but later on it was connecting.
Is this a know problem and is there any solution to this problem?